# HTML Email Template does not implement some CSS code

Tags: html, css, email

I try to write an HTML Email template that includes a button with a link and has a maximum width with the same margins left and right. However while some of the CSS part gets implemented some does not. For example for then button, the background and the font color is as I intended, however it does not add padding to the background and does not remove text-decorations.
A similar problem occurs when I try to set a maximum width for the overall Email with the same margins left and right. It implements the width but does not set the margins.
All of these things work out if I look at the template in a browser, only when I try to send it as an Email, it is displayed differently.

I already only use inline CSS and coded it as a table. For the button I wrote this code:

```
 <tr><td>
<h1> <a style="background-color: #8c30ff; color:white; text-decoration: none; padding: 0.5em" href="https://google.com"> Join now </a></h1>
 </td></tr>
```

And I tried setting the maximum width to this:

```
<table style="margin-bottom: 80px; margin-top: 80px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; max-width: 620px; align-content: ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Email clients all have different support for different HTML and CSS features. You can check [Can I email](https://www.caniemail.com) for detailed data about support across email clients.

`max-width` and `margin` in particular have mixed support, especially in *The Outlooks* on Windows. `max-width` is only supported in Outlook on Windows since Outlook 2016. And `margin` with `auto` values are not supported at all in Outlook on Windows. You must rely on tables with HTML attributes like `align="center"` for Outlook on Windows.

You can see an example of button code implementation by email developer Mark Robbins here: https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-code/link-button
And you can try this generator by Campaign Monitor: https://buttons.cm/